# When viewing on mobile strange line appears on the right side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've made the website responsive, but when I'm on a mobile device or on a small screen a strange line appears on the right[image of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLC64.jpg)

```css
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html
{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body
{
 overflow-x: hidden;
 color: #505962;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
         -o-animation: fadein 2s;
            animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

.navbar
{
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-brand
{
 height: 2.4rem;
}

.home-inner
{
 background-image: url('../img/imac-on-white-table.jpg');
 opacity: 0.3;
}

.caption
{
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 40%;
 z-index: 1;
}

.caption h3
{
 color: white;
 font-size: 2.4rem;
 padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

h3.heading
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.9rem;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 1.9rem;
}

.card
{
 margin: 2rem;
}

.card-img-top
{
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%);
 filter: grayscale(90%);
}

.footer .row
{
 background-color: #505962;
 padding: 1rem 2rem 3rem;
 color: #57C4DF;
}

.footer h3
{
 height: 2rem;
 margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

.sm
{
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 margin-top: .5rem;
 padding-left: .5rem;
}

.fa-facebook
{
 color: #2733D9;
}

.fa-linkedin
{
 color: #4875B4;
}

.fa-instagram
{
 color: #4E433C;
}

.fa:hover
{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.skillname
{
 margin-top: 1rem;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}


.skills
{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-radius: 5px;
}



.skill
{
 text-align: right;
 padding: 10px;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 5px
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-positive{
    0% { width: 0%; }
}
@keyframes animate-positive{
    0% { width: 0%; }
}

.html {width: 90%; background-color: #4CAF50;}
.css {width: 70%; background-color: #2196F3;}
.js {width: 80%; background-color: #B8860B;}
.symf {width: 65%; background-color: #32CD32;}
.php {width: 70%; background-color: #808080;}
.java {width: 40%; background-color: #FFA500;}

.landing
{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: table;
 background: #E9ECEF;
 z-index: -1;
}

.home-wrap
{
 clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.home-inner
{
 position: fixed;
 display: table;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
 will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title> Dustin Timmermans </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Nunito+Sans|Pacifico|Righteous|Play" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
 <body data-target="#menu">
  <div id="home">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Dustin Timmermans</a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#hobbies">Hobbies</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <div class="landing">
    <div class="home-wrap">
     <div class="home-inner">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="caption center-block text-center">
    <h3 style="font-family: Pacifico;">Dustin Timmermans</h3>
    <h4 style="font-family: Righteous;">Portfolio</h4>
   </div>

   <div id="about">
    <div class="jumbotron">
     <h3 class="heading">About</h3>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
       <h4>Who am I</h4>
       <p>My name is Dustin. Born in 1999 and living in the Hague. Currently I am a student Application and Mediadeveloper at <a href="https://www.rocmondriaan.nl/locatie-tinwerf-16">ROC Mondriaan</a>. I fluently speak and write English and Dutch. Also I am able
        to conversate in German.
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
       <h4>Skills</h4>
       <p class="progress">
        <p class="skillname">HTML5.0/TWIG</p>
        <div class="skills">
         <div class="skill html">90%</div>
        </div>
        <p class="skillname">CSS3.0</p>
        <div class="skills">
         <div class="skill css">70%</div>
        </div>
        <p class="skillname">JavaScript</p>
        <div class="skills">
         <div class="skill js">80%</div>
        </div>
        <p class="skillname">Symfony 3.4</p>
        <div class="skills">
         <div class="skill symf">65%</div>
        </div>
        <p class="skillname">PHP 7</p>
        <div class="skills">
         <div class="skill php">70%</div>
        </div>
        <p class="skillname">Java</p>
        <div class="skills">
         <div class="skill java">40%</div>
        </div>
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
       <h4>Why me</h4>
       <p>The reason why you should pick me as your next intern is, because when I learned to program, a whole new world opened up for me. I kept learning how to program and now I am able to make a fully animated, responsive and functional website.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="hobbies">
    <h3 class="heading">Hobbies</h3>
    <div class="row padding">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card text-center">
       <img src="img/motor.jpg" class="card-img-top">
       <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Motorcycle racing</h4>
        <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> I started racing on a motorcycle when I was 14 years old. I kept practicing and eventually I won the belgian championship. <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i></p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card text-center">
       <img src="img/me.jpg" class="card-img-top">
       <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Piano</h4>
        <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> I practice about 2 to 3 hours a day for almost 3 years now. When I am playing the piano it releases the tension. <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i></p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card text-center">
       <img src="img/karten.jpg" class="card-img-top">
       <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Karting</h4>
        <p><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> I started racing in a go-kart when I was 9 years old. I've competed in many championship and I've won several grand prix. <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i></p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid footer">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
       <h3>Dustin Timmermans</h3>
       <p>If you would like to check me out on social, <a href="mailto:dustin993246@gmail.com" class="fa fa-address-card-o" target="_top"></a>.</p><br>
       <strong>Social Media</strong><br>
       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dustin.timmermans.9" class="fa fa-facebook sm" target="_blank"></a>
       <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/dustin-timmermans-9a9421148/" class="fa fa-linkedin sm" target="_blank"></a>
       <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dustin_jt32/?hl=nl" class="fa fa-instagram sm" target="_blank"></a>
       <br><br>
       <p>© Copyright <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Dustin Timmermans</a> 2018</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried multiple things, but I don't know how to solve the problem. I've never had such a problem and I can't find any similar problems or questions. There are no further problems with the code, this is the only problem I have

Comment: Did you use element inspector to see if an element overlapses?

Comment: yes i did but nothing overlapsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.row
{
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

This isn't the right way to fix it but the quick and dirty way

Comment: Midorikawa, care to explain why this helps? :) I mean, _why_ is the browser (Chrome in this case, probably other WebKit browsers as well) applying this padding & margin even though it's not specified in the CSS? In Firefox, it renders properly even without this quirk so it seems very WebKit specific.